# Swift- Use data through app

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I am developing a quote of the day app so I created a quote class:

```
import Foundation
class Quote {
  let quote: String?
  let author: String?
  let backgroundImage: UIImage?
}
```

Then I created a loading screen that fetches the quote of the day data from an external database and creates a new instance from class Quote with the data fecthed:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
class LoadingViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //
    //check for internet connection and fecth data
    //
    //assign each data to a variable of quote object 
    ///q, a and bI are variables that represents quote, author and image

    let quoteOfTheDay = Quote()
    quoteOfTheDay.quote = q
    quoteOfTheDay.author = a
    quoteOfTheDay.backgroundImage = bI

    //---perform segue to main view controller
  }

}
```

After that, I want to share this quote of the day instance with all my other viewControllers until my app terminates. If it quits, the user will be directed to the loading view controller again to get the data. Otherwise, this quoteOfTheDay instance needs to stay active and be used by other screens as if it was cached while the app is active. How can I do this?

Note that I don't want to keep passing this instance with the use of prepareForSegue.

Thank You!

Comment: The Quote class itself is a model. Eventually I might actually move the fetching to the init method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a singleton like this:

```
import Foundation
class Quote {
  let quote: String?
  let author: String?
  let backgroundImage: UIImage?

  class var sharedInstance: Quote {
    struct Singleton {
      static let instance = Quote()
    }
    return Singleton.instance
  }
}
```

Now you can just call

```
Quote.sharedInstance
```

More details about design patterns in swift [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1)

You will find a lot of code demos for singleton in [here](https://github.com/hpique/SwiftSingleton)

@rmaddy and @adamPro raise important aspects I forgot to mention:

- You must be careful with this designer as it stays in memory for the
  life of your application (so no load images and videos here, and do
  not abuse this kind of designer too)
- Also as the name suggest you can    just create one instance of a singleton, if you think you may need to    in the future you should
  look for a more appropriate method to use
- Singletons does not have a very good view in most of the apple community, seems that this is changing with swift, however it is vastly used in other languages

Comment: If I implement this, how then should I create the singleton instance of the quote class? Just as if it was a normal class? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @TChad add a quote property on the singleton class.

Comment: @AdamPro13 Thank you very much for your help! It works! But, do you think it might give me some memory issues later on? Will the objects I create from the view controllers (such as: let question = Quote.sharedInstance) be kept on memory (along with the viewController) or will they be released?

Comment: Your quote object will stay in memory if the singleton has a strong reference to it but that likely won't cause any issues unless you start keeping thousands of them in memory. The singleton having a reference to the quote won't keep the view controller in memory unless you create a reference from the quote to the view controller.

Comment: Don't overuse singletons. This may work now but what happens when you need two different quotes in the app in different screens?

Comment: @rmaddy singleton is a design pattern where you just have one instance of a class through all the application, you can also have a dictionary inside it to hold multiple values, but if you need more than one class this is not the design to use definitely.

Comment: @AdamPro a singleton has to stay in memory through all the application life, it is done this way by design otherwise the values inside it would be lost

Comment: @IcaroNZ I understand the singleton design pattern. I'm just mentioning that it tends to get overused and it is a real pain to factor out when you later discover it was the wrong choice as the needs of the app change.

Comment: @rmaddy That's a good point. I might use a dictionary inside of the class then, since I'll eventually create a screen that displays the quotes from the last few days. I'm also trying to figure out how I'll handle quote background images. I think I'll use parse.com local datastore or NSUserDefaults.

Comment: @TChad for images I normally just save the URL to it in the singleton and recreate from it every time I need

Comment: @rmaddy I'm trying to make this singleton hold multiple values (i.e multiple quotes of the day). How can I do this by the method you mentioned(putting a dictionary inside of it)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a static property in your Quote class to store the quote of the day.

```
class Quote: NSObject {
     static var quoteOfTheDay: Quote?

     //Other Quote Code...
}
```

Then to access:

```
let quote = Quote.quoteOfTheDay as Quote!
```

Keep in mind though that if the quoteOfTheDay is nil when you try to access it using the method above, the app will crash. So you'll want to either consider accessing it in a more secure way or not storing it as an optional.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered writing the Quote object to a disk archive?  Perhaps in Application Support?  By using a naming convention that utilizes the date the quote is generated, a user could then retrieve it even in a later launch on the same day.  You could then delete it on the next launch on a different day.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry but I'm not familiar to writing in Application Support. On the loading screen I'm getting the current date(NSDate) and, after converting it to a String, asynchronously looking for a quote on my Parse.com database with the date the same as the one on the app.

Comment: I was considering making the instance I created ( quoteOfTheDay) global to the entire project so that any vc could access it. However, I was afraid this could lead to some memory issues later on. Do you recommend this approach? Also, I was thinking about abandoning the Quotes objects and, after fetching the data, storing the data with NSUserDefault and using it getting the data when necessary. What are your thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Writing and accessing [Application Support](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) is not difficult to learn, and can be accessed by any class at any time in your application.  Plus, it protects your user from phone call interruptions, power failures, etc.   If something happens, your app can restore the quote of the day from the disk.